# What's the most efficient way to inject behavior into all my entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, extension-methods

I'm converting a large data model from an old Microsoft data access library to Entity Framework 4. I'd like to "inject" these two methods into most, if not all, of the entities that have been generated from the existing database into my EF model:

```
    public bool Deleted
    {
        get { return this.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Deleted; }
        set 
        {
            if (value)
                Context.DeleteObject(this);
        }
    }

    public bool Inserted
    {
        get { return this.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Added; }
        set
        {
            if (value)
                Context.AddObject(this.GetType().Name, this);
        }
    }
```

Rather than creating a partial class for each entity (there are over 100), what's the better way to add these methods to all the entities in the model?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: add to the common entity base class?

Comment: @Mitch, thanks for the suggestion. I'd already tried to add a partial class for the EntityObject, but evidently EntityObject doesn't see an EntityState property.

Answer (score 4):

I'd modify the EF T4 template to generate these properties automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @Daz's (somewhat sparse) answer:  Right-click in the designer and select `Add Code Generation Item...`, then `ADO.NET Entity Object Generator.`  It will create a template that generates exactly the same code that the compiler already creates, which you can then customize.  Open it up, it's pretty easy to see how to modify it.  It's designed for exactly the purpose you describe.

[Here's a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558520) describing things in detail.

Comment: @Daz, thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping to do it outside the code generator. I was thinking an aspect or extension method could be developed to add this behavior to the classes. But I may mod the code gen if no other solution is presented.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new base class for your entities, it should inherit the current one you are using and extend its members with that code.

Comment: Peter's correct. I want this behavior to be outside of the code generation, or want to modify the code generation to have these properties.

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods do the trick. But of course they are **methods**, not proper properties like you make in your sample (extension properties don't exist yet in the framework, only extension methods).

```
public static class EntityObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDeleted(this EntityObject obj)
    {
        return obj.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    public static bool Delete(this EntityObject obj)
    {
        Context.DeleteObject(obj);
    }

    public static bool IsInserted(this EntityObject obj)
    {
        return obj.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Added;
    }

    public static bool Insert(this EntityObject obj)
    {
        Context.AddObject(obj.GetType().Name, obj);
    }
}
```

Undoubtly this solution is the most elegant and the nearest from your demand. No need to touch the code generation nor to duplicate the same code on all your classes. If something has to evolve in these methods, the changes will be done in one single place and all your classes will take benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I am looking for is a way to have the properties automatically be available for all my entities so I didn't have to modify every single reference in the tens of thousands of lines of client code.

Comment: @John It was precisely what I had understood from your question. Doesn't my answer fullfill this requirement ?

Comment: Your solution creates methods. In order to minimize the changes to the client code, I was looking for property wrappers instead. You have provided *a* solution, but not one that allows me to use the existing client code.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Unfortunately there are not thousands of options. Either you make 1000 changes on 1000 classes or your make 1 change on a well chosen place. Knowing that... 1/ You can leave the calls unchanged provided you add properties by code generation but you don't want to. 2/ extensions can only be methods : it forces to change all the calls and you don't want to. 3/ Properties can be added to a common ancestor class : you tried with adding a partial class to the EntityObject but it seems you didn't manage to. Err... looks like a compromise will maybe have to be considered...

Comment: Ssithra, I appreciate your efforts. There are certainly other ways to do this, and all of them will cause trouble down the road as EF or its template gets rev'd, or if we adopt DevForce, or the model gets updated, or the application evolves. It turned out that not all of the entities needed these properties, so we just created the ones we needed. Also, your sample above wouldn't work at runtime. For example, the pluralization of the collection would cause Context.AddObject(obj.GetType().Name, obj) to fail, so it couldn't be generic that way.